# Add buttons at runtime that can be accessed by any method on iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, runtime

I tried creating UIButtons from an Array of objects. I created these successfully by using

```
float x=0,y=0;
for( NSMutableDictionary *dict in places) 
{
    NSLog(@"x: %f",x);
    x=x+25;
    y=y+25;// Vary these depending on where you want the buttons to be
    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,25,25)] autorelease];
    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self addSubview:button];
}
```

but I need some way to make all of these buttons accesible by other methods in my class, particularly a method that is triggered by the CLLocation delegate (or some other ways, even by user interaction) and which animates any of the buttons.

Hope anyone can help me!

btw: the object "places" is an Array of MutableDictionaries.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mutable collection for keeping the references to the buttons. If you need to have them ordered somehow, create NSMutableArray, if not, create NSMutableSet. In the header file declare the ivar like **NSMutableSet buttonsSet**, then in the class implementation:

```
float x=0,y=0;
buttonsSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
for( NSMutableDictionary *dict in places) {
    NSLog(@"x: %f",x);
    x=x+25;
    y=y+25;// Vary these depending on where you want the buttons to be
    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,25,25)] autorelease];
    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [buttonsSet addObject:button];
    [self addSubview:button];
}
```

Note that the buttons are accessible also through *self.subviews* array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but after adding the buttons to the view, I would like to animate them so, getting them from a NSSet or NSArray is not exactly what i need because those are different objects from the ones that have been added as subviews (unless there is another way to animate them that I'm not aware of). The self.subviews array might work for what I need but I don't know how to choose the button I need from that array.

Comment: I still think that if you put them in the array or set these are the same objects. What you put in the collection is the pointer to the button, not the copy, so this should work just fine. If you prefer the *self.subviews* approach, you can distinguish between your buttons by using *tag* property. Just set the tag on the button when you create it, and then get it with `[self viewWithTag:theTag]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @lawicko ! you were absolutely right about the objects being pointers and not objects per se! I already tried it and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(60, 327, 210, 32); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
        [myButton setTitle:@"Madhavan" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:myButton];
```